# UIImageView on TableViewCell missing its constraints on clicking cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitableview

**Requirement:**

I'm doing a `sideBar navigation`,using `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` inside it.Inside `UITableViewCell` ,there is an `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.i want the `UIImageView` to have same **height** and **width**,and i have given constraints for it.

**Issue:**

BUT AFTER CLICKING ON EACH CELL,THE SIZE OF IMAGEVIEW CHANGES(CONSTRAINTS MISSING) AND OVERLAPS THE LABEL.

i did all constraints in storyboard only and im doing in swift 3
please help me.

**Code work:**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
     cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row]
     let iconName = images[indexPath.row]
    //print("\(iconName)")
     let image = UIImage(named: iconName)
   // print("The loaded image: \(image)")
     cell.imageViews.image = image
    
         return cell
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  
   tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

**Screent Shot**

[image: At the time of loading]

[image: On clicking each cell]

[image: constraints on images]

Comment: Show your didSelectForRow if implemented?

Comment: cell.imageView.maskToBound = true , try this

Comment: @Himanshu   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

Comment: Why you are deselecting the cell on `didselect` method. Show your prototype-cell Contraints.

Comment: even if i avoid deselecting,the result is same--@the_dahiya_boy

Comment: @JaisanMathew check the content mode of imageview

Comment: @JaisanMathew also can you update the questions to show the constraints you added ( a screenshot of the storyboard of nib)

Comment: i tried 1st three content modes,but my bad luck  @Raon

Comment: are you using different images for showing selected and deselect states?

Comment: no,the same image itself @Misha

Comment: what are your label's constraints?

Comment: I guess it is limitation or some internal procession will remove UIImageView constraints if not set it at first time, I mean, you should set cell.imageViews.image = image even you not get image from server or local files.
Our workaround is given default image all the time, make the constraints alive

Answer (score 0):

```
        for viw in cell.contentView.subviews {
        if ((viw as? UIImageView) != nil) {
            viw.removeFromSuperview()
        }else if ((viw as? UILabel) != nil) {
            viw.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Use this code after the cell creation [from second line]. Try it.